# Linking Firebase Objects

Tags: firebase

Now I am not sure whether this exists in Firebase already or whether perhaps this would be a great idea for the Firebase team to implement?!

I have a growing collection of photos on my Nfolio Firebase database. Lets imagine I wanted to create a list of our favourite photos to present under the "Featured photos" page. Would it be possible to create a list of keys? In other words a list of references to other FB objects? So that if anyone updates the original objects in any way, the featured list automatically updates?

Answer (score 4):

In the root object, you could create a favorite photos object that has the full path of the individual photos in your photos db. So if your fb is structured like:

```
db
  favorites
    user1/1
    user2/2
    user2/3
  users
    user1
      photos
        1
    user2
      photos
        2
        3
```

You can simply keep references of the individual photos with the path provided.

Comment: In the meantime I am considering doing something along the lines of what @sean suggests. I still think it would be very cool if Firebase were to add "linked refs" if that were possible.